# Embedding Angular application as a widget

Tags: javascript, angular

I've build an Angular app that would be embedded onto a page as a widget, however unable to get it running at full height, is there a better way I can inject this Angular application onto a page?

Prior to using Angular i've done this using an iFrame and having the document embedded post a message back to the parent page to resize the iFrame to the document height which worked fine, however the document.body.scrollHeight in Angular seems to behave differently and is the window size

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that my .main-container was display:flex; which was making document.body.scrollHeight return the window size rather than the document.

Changing .main-container to display: block fixed the issue